# cucumber: how to enter text from keyboard into textfield?

Tags: iphone, cucumber, calabash

i am using type_into_keyboard("abc") to enter text into textfield named as "username" from keyboard but it is not working.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
Then I enter "abd" into the "username" input field
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add this custom function to the "_steps.rb" file

```
Then /^I enter constant text "([^\"]*)" to text field number (\d+)$/ do |texts,index|

    index = index.to_i
    screenshot_and_raise "Index should be positive (was: #{index})" if (index<=0)
    clearTextfield(index-1)
    enterDataToTextfieldNum(texts, index-1)
    sleep(STEP_PAUSE)
end

def enterDataToTextfieldNum(text, index)
  index = index.to_i
  text = text.to_s
  if index>=0
        sleep(0.2)
        touch("textField index:#{index}")
        sleep(0.4)
        await_keyboard
        sleep(0.2)
        keyboard_enter_text("#{text}")
        sleep(0.2)
        done
        sleep(0.3)
  end
end

def clearTextfield(index)
    index = index.to_i

    if query("textField index:#{index}",:text).first
      length=query("textField index:#{index}",:text).first.length
    else
      length=0
    end
    if (index>=0)&&(length>0)
        touch("textField index:#{index}")
        await_keyboard
      for i in 0..length-1
        keyboard_enter_char("Delete",false)
      end
    end
end
```

Then you can call it in calabash feature file

```
Then I enter constant text "Old road" to text field number 3
```

here i used textfileld number but if you want you can edit it to use text field name. If you need help on that please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: when I run this it touches textfield,keyboard appears and it saying  the following error                                                   Time out waiting for UIAutomation run-loop for command uia.typeString('Old road'). Waiting for index:2 (RunLoop::TimeoutError)
      ./features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb:24:in `enterDataToTextfieldNum'
      ./features/step_definitions/my_first_steps.rb:11:in `/^I enter constant text "([^\"]*)" to text field number (\d+)$/'
      features/my_first.feature:8:in `Then I enter constant text "Old road" to text field number 1

Comment: Yaseen , can you mention your step definition and the step completely, here so I can review.